# How can I get the keystrokes using java

Tags: java, client-server, keystroke

I am learning to develop a simple remote desktop application, I successfully managed to create the server and the client classes. they connect to each other using the socket but what I am trying to do now is to get the keystrokes that the client types. for example if the clients types something on word document. the server should obtain the keystrokes. how can I get the keystrokes using java.

Comment: What client side technology are you using: Swing, JavaFX, SWT etc?

Comment: Doesn't a remote desktop application *send* keystrokes to the document? Also Swing can't obtain keystrokes from another application.

Comment: Java can't capture the global key strokes from the os (or at least, it doesn't provide a means by which you can process them). You will need to investigate a JNA/JNI solution. Do search for "Java JNI keyboard hook"

Answer (score 0):

```
public void pressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        s.write(e.getID()); //push to server
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally discouraged. Please edit your answer to explain how and why this answer solves the problem.